# Magento 2 I Want To Show Both Including/Excluding Tax Price Only On Product Detail Page

Tags: magento2, tax

I want to show Both including/excluding tax price only on Product Detail Page.
and other pages I want to show excluding tax price this done via admin tax configuration.
Now I want to show only Both including/excluding tax price only on Product Detail Page.